# Is it possible to provide values from MATLAB function to Simulink in the real time?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I created a matlab function in a Simulink environment which gives 200 values. I would like to use those 200 values for 2 seconds. Basically mapping the time.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you clarify your question?  What do you mean by "use those 200 values"?

Comment: Have your tried the MATLAB function block in Simulink?

Comment: I am using a Matlab Function block for calculating a variable. The output variable has 200 values (vector) for a single time step. I want to use these 200 values for two seconds one by one. It means for 1 value for 0.01 second. How can I do this.